Showing lines as stacked bars side-by-side in QGIS
In QGIS 3.38 I am working on a project for a nonprofit, and I'm visualizing value data joined to a line feature by segment. There are three lines across the route, with left ditch, road, and right ditch data being displayed together to show how the data changes along the route. Using three individual lines looks a bit messy, and I would love to show the lines as stacked bars side-by-side, but consistent throughout the entire line.
I was able to buffer the road line and then manually adjust the segments. Then, I exported the layer twice and manually adjusted each of those polygons to match the curve. This was manageable for this 16-segment feature, but I may need to make another map for this project with many more segments. How to make this workflow more robust?

The "cuts" or segments are part of the data. Each segment is a section of road that had individuals counted, and the distance of each segment is used to calculate the density of individuals found in that section of the road and each ditch.

Using line symbol with an offset will give a close result, the main difference will be at the extremity of the segment where you may get superposition or gap.
There are two way to implement this

With symbol level and using data defined override for symbology.
In the below picture I use four symbol layer (all Simple line), the
first 3 for road, left and right ditch, the fourth to give a thin
black outline to all other symbol.
The first three line have an 1.8 stroke width and the Left/Right
ditch line have an offset of 2 (positive for right, negative for
left). the fourth black line has no offset and a with of 6.2.
For the symbology I used data defined override for line color with
the following expression :
ramp_color('color_ramp_name',value)
as the value need to be in the [0, 1] range you need to normalise
the value so the expression become :
ramp_color( 'color_ramp_name',(("Field_Name"-minimum("Field_Name"))/(maximum("Field_Name")-minimum("Field_Name"))))
(of course remplace color_ramp_name by the actual name of the color
ramp you want to use and Field_Name by the name of the respective
field holding the value for road/left/right)

Wile this solution has the avantage of keeping everything in the
same layer you wont be able to automatically generate a legend

Alternatively duplicate the layer 3 time (to get 4 line as before but in four different layer) and use a graduated symbology for the first three layer
(don't forget to give an offset to the left and right ditch). In the
below image I used the same width and offset as before but a more
colorful color ramp.

This second way will give you a legend.


